# Android RxJava Room query not executing with Completable

Tags: android, rx-java, android-room

I am performing a query on my Room database and wrapping it in a Completable.
The @Query is actually a DELETE with parameters. The function does not return anything.

When I call the function which is wrapped in the Completable, nothing happens. I log the output and my logs dont get printed.

See below:

```
override fun deleteOrder(orderId: String, shipmentId: String): Completable {
    Log.d("Test", "Deleting::orderId::$orderId::shipmentId::$shipmentId")

    return Completable.fromAction {
        Log.d("Test", "DELETING")
        db.getOrderDao().deleteOrder(orderId, shipmentId)
    }.doOnComplete {
        Log.d("Test", "DO_ON_COMPLETE")
        UploadOrderJob.submitJob(context, orderId, shipmentId, true)
    }
}
```

So the first Log gets printed with the correct values, but nothing else.
My Dao is as follows:

```
@Query("DELETE FROM pending_orders WHERE order_id=:orderId AND shipment_id=:shipmentId")
fun deleteOrder(orderId: String, shipmentId: String)
```

I'm doing something wrong here but I'm new to RxJava so not sure what's wrong.
Going back to the original call site that triggers this code, I'm subscribing as follows:

```
fun deleteOrder(shipmentId: String) {
    currentOrder.value?.let {
        deleteOrderUseCase.deleteOrder(it.id, shipmentId)
            .applySchedulers()
            .subscribe { onOrderRemoved() }
            .hold(this)
    }
}
```

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

EDIT: Some extension functions in the code:

```
fun Completable.applySchedulers(): Completable {
    return this
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .doOnError { throwable -> throwable.printStackTrace() }
}


fun Disposable.hold(holder: CompositeDisposablesHolder) = holder.hold(this)

interface CompositeDisposablesHolder {
    fun hold(disposable: Disposable)
}
```

Comment: What's `hold`? Typically, when something won't run apparently on Android, there is a disposed `CompositeDisposable` that disposes the sequence right away. Probably in `onPause`/`onDestroy`.

Comment: @akarnokd Sorry, both `applySchedulers` and `hold` are extension functions. I've added them to the main question, The `hold` function just adds to a `CompositeDisposable` in the base ViewModel, and when the `ViewModel.onCleared()` function gets called, the `CompositeDisposable` gets cleared.

Comment: Add `doOnDispose` before `applySchedulers` and log if it gets executed.

Comment: @akarnokd I added a log output but I'm not seeing it in Logcat. The code doesn't seem to be even entering the Completable block.

Comment: Can you debug your code? Single step through the various subscribe and see where it is derailed? Also android log tends to suppress repeated text so try adding a random number to those log strings. Also, just for testing, remove the call to `hold`.

Comment: @akarnokd I removed hold and its working. Thank you! I don't know why though, its just calling a `compositeDisposable.add()`. I don't see how adding it to a list would stop it being called when `onDispose` is not even called! Thanks again :)

Comment: Actually, as per the docs: `CompositeDisposable.add() -> Adds a disposable to this container or disposes it if the container has been disposed.` So it must have been disposed somewhere.

Comment: Do you have `compositeDisposable.dispose()` in your code?

Comment: Just in my base ViewModel, where I go: `override fun onCleared() = compositeDisposable.dispose()`. This is overriding `ViewModel.onCleared()`.